# Query invalidation not working on query with dynamic query key

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Query:

```
export const useQueryExample = (
  page: number,
  project: Lowercase<`${Projects}`>
) =>
  useQuery<ResponseDto>({
    queryKey: [page, QueryClientKeys.QUERY_KEY],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await ApiService.getApiExample([project], {
        page,
        pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
      });
      return response.data;
    },
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity,
  });
```

This query has dynamic key `page` for pagination fetch.

I'm calling upper query invalidation from a mutation `onSuccess` handler

Mutation:

```
export const useMutationExample = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation<
    undefined,
    unknown,
    { project: Lowercase<`${Projects}`>; data: RequestDto }
  >({
    mutationKey: [QueryClientKeys.MUTATION_KEY],
    mutationFn: async ({
      project,
      data,
    }: {
      project: Lowercase<`${Projects}`>;
      data: RequestDto;
    }) => {
      const response = await ApiService.postApiExample([project], data, {
        headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      });
      return response.data;
    },
    onSuccess: (_data, { project }) => {
      navigate(`/some/in-app/route`);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [QueryClientKeys.QUERY_KEY],
      });
    },
  });
};
```

For some reason invalidation doesn't work if the query has dynamic `page` key - meaning if I remove it from the keys array, it works as expected. Why is that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at TkDodo's blog on keys (https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys), it seems that the order of keys in array is important. Defining the `queryKey` like:

```
queryKey: [QueryClientKeys.QUERY_KEY, page]
```

so, putting the page (which is of type number) param after the general query key, works as expected when invalidating queries. I still don't get the actual reason behind the importance of keys' order in the array.